# Binary and unary minus operator in Lexical Analyzer

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

So, I am doing a lexical analysis of a TOY programming language using flex. I am currently stuck at the following point.

**Minus sign:** As we know the minus sign can have two meanings by defining them as binary or unary operators (I also know you can discard two meanings and just say that -2 is the same as 0-2). Firstly, I have only studied lexical analyzers as of now and I don't know anything about parsers. So, should I care about distinguishing these two minus signs, becomes sometimes the analyzer will print -2 as a Numeric literal and sometimes - as an operator and 2 as a numeric literal? Or can this kind of clubbing of two literals be done during parsing? If yes, then should I only define positive numbers and - as a unary operator?

Comment: During lexical analysis, you don't need to care about the meaning of lexemes. Just define `-` as `minus`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In lex, how do I differentiate between '-' (subtraction) operator and an integer '-3'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386695/in-lex-how-do-i-differentiate-between-subtraction-operator-and-an-integer)

Comment: I know that C++ compiler implements a negative integer as `-` + `positive integer`. This causes some problems when you try to write very big negative integers. However, I see no reason why a parser couldn't just concatenate an unary `-` with the rest of the integer.

Answer (score 2):

Things get really complicated if you try to analyse signed integers as single tokens. For example, you will have to avoid analysing `x-1` as { `x`, `-1` }, since that `-` is an operator.

If you analyse signed integers as two tokens -- a sign and then an integer -- then you will get a sensible parse. There are only two issues:

1. You really don't want to evaluate `-1` at runtime. It's a constant value, and it should be evaluated at compile time. But that's no different from any other constant expression. `(1+1)` should ideally be folded to `2` at compile time. Constant folding is a relatively easy optimization to implement, although you should get things working first.
2. In two's complement, the smallest negative integer (-2147483648 if you're using signed 32-bit integers) is integer overflow if the integer part is separated from the sign. `2147483648`. There are a number of ways of dealing with this, most of which lead to some kind of parsing quirk. For example, a C  compiler targetting a 32-bit `int` will assign a wider type than `int` to 2147483648, and that means that -2147483647 and -2147483648 are unexpectedly different types. (That's why `INT_MIN` is usually `#define`d as `(-2147483647 - 1)`.) On the other hand, if you just assume that the compiler is running in a 2's-complement environment with integers wrapping around, then you'll get the right value for `-2147483648`. But you'll get the same value for `2147483648`, which should be flagged with a diagnostic. For a student project with a toy language, these quirks are probably innocuous, but you should make some attempt to document them.

Comment: I was also thinking the same thing. Thanks for confirming it. :)